# Custom annotations in scala

Tags: scala, annotations, case-class

I am working in Scala programming language. I want to create custom annotations to annotate the fields of case class.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420334/how-to-define-and-use-custom-annotations-in-scala) thread show how to create it but there are two problems I am facing for my scenario

1. There can be . in the annotations. e.g. @abc.xyz
2. I want to create annotations without parameters. so I cannot create case classes

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad. 1 - you can use backticks to have `.` in name but there I see 0 reasons why you should (you can just put `xyz` in `abc` package)

```
// possible but it's anti-pattern
class `abc.xyz` extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

case class Test(
  @`abc.xyz` field: String
)
```

```
// better
package my.abc

class xyz extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

// elsewere

import my.abc

case class Test(
  @abc.xyz field: String
)
```

Ad. 2 what annotations parameters have to do with case classes? Annotation does NOT have to be a `case class`. Some people use it because in macros they can use pattern matching on materialized annotation value, but that's it.

```
case class Foo() extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class Bar extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

case class Test(
  @Foo foo: String,
  @Bar bar: String
)
```

Comment: I went with Ad 1 better sol. follow up question. I want to annotate with "@abc.xyz" and one more level e.g. "@abc.xyz.pqr" together. If I create another package xyz in abc and put pqr class in that, then I get this error: "package abc contains object and package with same name: xyz". How can I resolve this? Is it possible with class inside class? if yes how?